# Microsoft Edge crashes/freezes when viewing a page

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I need to test a web app that is under development, in Microsoft Edge but the browser freezes every time the page is loaded (same happens in different laptops with Edge) and I need to close the browser window. The web app works pretty fine in other browsers (even in IE9, IE10). I tried Edge with some other sites and there was no such issue, however, I found similar complaints about Edge freezes but still no cure for my case.

Does anyone know what might cause the problem?

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: Without seeing any html it would be hard to say. I've seen similar issues in an app I'm developing for iPad. Works great in the iPad but open it up in Edge and it slows to a crawl... I'm using angular material and UI-Grid in an angular app. The only think I can recommend without seeing  any code is to comment out things and reload your page and see if your performance improves.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not a performance issue, the login screen works fine but once I login, nothing is responding, no hovers, no clicks, even the refresh button.